# HOw to use jsonschema2pojo in maven's POM

Tags: java, maven-plugin, pojo

I have a JSON File and I want to convert it to POJO, for this I am using the plugin of org.jsonschema2pojo in maven. I am not able to generate the resultant pojo.Here's the snippet from pom.xml

```
<build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>


                        <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.4.23</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
                            <targetPackage>${basedir}/src/main/resources/result</targetPackage>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```

I am using the generate sources goal in maven. My expectation is that it should give me pojo files at ${basedir}/src/main/resources/result  location. However I am getting so. Please help me out.
Thanks,
Rajit

Answer (score 6):

You want to use `<outputDirectory>` instead of `<targetPackage>`. More details here:

- http://joelittlejohn.github.io/jsonschema2pojo/site/0.4.23/generate-mojo.html#outputDirectory
- http://joelittlejohn.github.io/jsonschema2pojo/site/0.4.23/generate-mojo.html#targetPackage

Target package is the Java package you want your types to use, e.g. `com.youcompany.model`.

Also, typically you want the generated output to go into the `target` directory, not `src`. Derived files usually go there since anything inside `target` is usually omitted from source control. You don't need to specify `outputDirectory` if you don't want to, by default the generated output will go into `/target/java-gen`.

Comment: Thnks for the reply. I have removed the line" <targetPackage>${basedir}/src/main/resources/result</targetPackage>"

but still the files are not getting generated in the target folder.
Now my configuration file is
<configuration>
     <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/jsonSample.json</sourceDirectory>
</configuration>
Note: Iam using generate-sources phase of maven to build.
My target folder now contains only maven-status folder.

Please suggest.

Comment: How to get a jar file created from the generated pojo .class files using maven?

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol mvn package

Comment: If you are generating code from JSON (not from JSON schema), use <sourceType>json</sourceType> in your jsonschema2pojo plugin configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Below code works for me.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>1</id>
            <configuration>
                <annotationStyle>jackson2</annotationStyle>
                <includeAdditionalProperties>false</includeAdditionalProperties>
                <sourcePaths>
                    <sourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resource/jsd/your_schema.json</sourcePath>
                </sourcePaths>
                <targetPackage>your target package</targetPackage>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>2</id>
            <configuration>
                <annotationStyle>jackson2</annotationStyle>
                <includeAdditionalProperties>false</includeAdditionalProperties>
                <sourcePaths>
                    <sourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resource/jsd/your_schema2.json</sourcePath>
                </sourcePaths>
                <targetPackage>your target package</targetPackage>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: yes , it works for me . i tried same script.

Answer (score 2):

Use both targetPackage and outputDirectory.

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
          <targetPackage>com.your.package</targetPackage>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```